# What does this mean: "Johnsy" was familiar for Joanna

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> At the top of a squatty, three-story brick Sue and Johnsy had their
>   studio. **"Johnsy" was familiar for Joanna**. One was from Maine; the
>   other from California. They had met at the table d'hôte of an Eighth
>   Street "Delmonico's," and found their tastes in art, chicory salad and
>   bishop sleeves so congenial that the joint studio resulted

---

This passage is from the story named "[The Last Leaf](http://www.online-literature.com/o_henry/1303/)" written by O. Henry.

Comment: I'm a native speaker (northeastern American English) and I had to read this sentence twice to make sure I understood it correctly. I am dimly aware of the phrase "familiar name" meaning "nickname" but I've never seen the phrase "X was familiar for Y". Just so you know, you might not be easily understood if you try to use this phrase in your day-to-day life `:)`

Comment: @apsillers: "Johnsy was familiar for Joanna" operates under the same principle as "short for" (as in "Theo is short for "Theodore"). Other adjectives could apply as well: *exalted for*, *Greek for*, *formal for*, etc.

Comment: @Robusto What does _exalted_ for mean? Can't find it in Google.

Comment: @EddieKal: You won't find every potential combination of words in Google, nor is Google the arbiter of what is "correct" or "good" or "possible" in English. The point is, there are many potential "adjective for noun" combinations using that pattern.

Comment: @Robusto I understand your point. I am just trying to figure out what _somehing is exalted for something._ means, as you have suggested it is a meaningful combination. I understand the rest on your list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It just means that "Johnsy" was a familiar ***name***—we would call it a "nickname"—for Joanna.

See [**nickname**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nickname). Also, *familiar* is used in the sense meaning ["friendly" or "informal"](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/familiar).

Answer (score 3):

I would take it to mean it was an intimate name for someone whose real or given name was Joanna. Sue is living with a person named Joanna who prefers to be addressed as Johnsy. Much as in my case "Jack" is familiar for John. Someone who actually knows me will call me Jack, someone who doesn't know me very well will call me John. In other words, someone who is familiar with me will use my preferred name much like a member of my family might.